# start IntentService always in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

this is my Broadcast_Receiver

```
public class Broadcast_Receiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, Notification_Intent_Service.class));
    }
}
```

and this is my IntentService

```
public class Notification_Intent_Service extends IntentService {

    public Notification_Intent_Service() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("s","w");
    }
}
```

at the end  my manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Service.Broadcast_Receiver"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".Service.Notification_Intent_Service" />
```

i install the application and its didnt show any message tell me that's it run

did its want to start it from Activity ? if i must start it from Activity how can i make it auto start at any time without start it from Activity

Comment: You have to have an `Activity` that you've run at least once after installation to bring your app out of the _stopped_ state, or your boot Receiver won't work.

Comment: @MikeM. i have multi Activity in my app did u mean i must start Broadcast_Receiver  from Activity

Comment: No, I mean you need to have run your app at least once before you reboot. You also need the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.